# Placing C++ Text Into Square Shape

Tags: c++

I am trying to take a string of text in C++ and encode it by placing it within a square shape. For example, "Purple Shirt" would encode to...

```
P U R P
L E   S
H I R T
```

The function should then print the decoded string by reading it column by column. For example, "PLHUEIR RPST" would be the decoded version of the encoded square above.

The width of the square is passed by reference into the function. Any extra space within the square should be occupied by blank spaces & a period at the end. For example, if the passed width was 5, "Purple Shirt" would encode to...

```
P U R P L
E   S H I
R T     .
```

This would be printed out as "PERU TRS PH IL."

Comment: Nice. Do you need someone to hand out Free Code, or do you have an actual question? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help].

Comment: Interesting, that looks that an implementation of a simple cypher algorithm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to explain in more detail **how** the words will be split into the rows and columns. How many rows and columns should a word be split into?

Let's begin.

```
// These attributes needs be programmed
// If a word is 4 letters long, should the matrix be in the form 2x2?
// If a word is 5 letters long? What happens then?

var rowLength;
var columnLength;
var index = 0;

String[][] letters = new String[row][col];
String word = "ABCD";


for (int i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
        letters[i][j] = word.at(index++);
    }
}
```

This should save your word in the matrix, given by how you choose to implement it. X*Y. By traversing the matrix in the reversed order, column by row. You should now be able to build the new word in the form described.

```
// Here we can build the new word ('newWord') by appending each letter
// from the array of letters[][] declared above.
String newWord = "";
for (int x = 0; x < rowLength; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < columnLength; y++) {
        newWord.append(letters[x][y]);
    }
}
return newWord;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a matrix with width equal to the chosen square width and height equal to the input string's length / chosen width + 1. Store the string in this matrix, then print the matrix out by column. I'll leave the actual coding as an exercise for the reader.